# Nested CASE statement in UPDATE SET clause

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update, case

I am attempting to switch a value based on a set of conditions and I have noticed that where I have a nested CASE statement within the SET clause of my UPDATE expression, the columns are not updating.

When a simple CASE expression existis the columns appear to be updating. However, for the OVERRIDDEN_CHECK_NUMBER and OVERRIDDEN_AMOUNT in this example, the columns are not updating.

The OVERRIDDEN_DATE, OVERRIDDEN_USER_ID, CHECK_NO and AMOUNT columns in the UPDATE are updating without issue.

Can anyone tell me why the OVERRIDDEN_CHECK_NUMBER and OVERRIDDEN_AMOUNT will not update in this UPDATE statement?

Are nested CASE statements not tallowed in the SET clause of the UPDATE expression?

**SQL EXAMPLE**

```
UPDATE WAREHOUSE.BANK_STATEMENT_ACTIVITY
    SET OVERRIDDEN_CHECK_NO       = --(CASE :btn                                          
                                        (CASE WHEN (:btn = '1') THEN CASE WHEN '141973' = '141973' THEN NULL
                                                                           WHEN '141973' != '999999' THEN LPAD(TRIM(141973), 12, '0')
                                                                      END
                                        WHEN (:btn = '2') THEN '1740 - Previously Paid Warrant'
                                        ELSE NULL
                                    END),
        OVERRIDDEN_AMOUNT         = --(CASE :btn
                                        (CASE WHEN (:btn = '1') THEN CASE WHEN 253.20 = 253.20 THEN NULL
                                                                           WHEN 253.20 != 999.99 THEN LPAD(TRIM(253.20), 12, '0')
                                                                      END
                                        WHEN (:btn = '2') THEN NULL
                                        ELSE NULL
                                    END),
        OVERRIDDEN_DATE           = SYSDATE,
        OVERRIDDEN_USER_ID        = 1009,
        CHECK_NO                  = (CASE :btn
                                        WHEN '1' THEN LPAD(TRIM(999999), 12, '0')
                                        WHEN '2' THEN '142775'
                                        ELSE NULL
                                        END),
        AMOUNT                    = (CASE :btn
                                        WHEN '1' THEN TRIM(78.60)
                                        WHEN '2' THEN TRIM(253.20)
                                        ELSE NULL
                                        END)
        WHERE TO_NUMBER(CHECK_NO) = (CASE :btn
                                        WHEN '1' THEN '141973'
                                        WHEN '2' THEN '142775'
                                        ELSE NULL
                                    END)
        AND AMOUNT                = (CASE :btn
                                        WHEN '1' THEN 78.60
                                        WHEN '2' THEN 253.20
                                        ELSE NULL
                                    END)
        AND TRUNC(LOAD_DATE)      = (CASE :btn
                                        WHEN '1' THEN TRUNC(LOAD_DATE)
                                        WHEN '2' THEN (SELECT (MAX(LOAD_DATE)) FROM WAREHOUSE.BANK_STATEMENT_ACTIVITY)
                                        ELSE NULL
                                        END)
        AND BANKACCTNO            = (SELECT LONGDESC 
                                     FROM TCMS.COMPLEMENTARY_VALIDATIONS
                                     WHERE TEXTCODE = 'BANKACCT'
                                     AND CODE = 80);
```

***EDIT***

After fixing the logival issue that @mathguy pointed out the update query via the editor worked.  However, when executing this via the PL/SQL pacakge the table update fails.

Here is the before update:

[Before - result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kHG84.png)

Her is the after result:

[After - result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8IuuX.png)

They are identical.

**This is the actual package procedure:**

```
PROCEDURE UpdateBankStatementActivity( btn IN VARCHAR2)
AS
BEGIN
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( 'UpdateBankStatementActivity - btn: ' || btn );
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( 'UpdateBankStatementActivity - bsa_rec.OVERRIDDEN_CHECK_NO: ' || bsa_rec.OVERRIDDEN_CHECK_NO || CHR(10) ||
                                                    'bsa_rec.OVERRIDDEN_AMOUNT: ' || bsa_rec.OVERRIDDEN_AMOUNT || CHR(10) ||
                                                    'bsa_rec.CHECK_NO: ' || bsa_rec.CHECK_NO || CHR(10) ||
                                                    'bsa_rec.AMOUNT: ' || bsa_rec.AMOUNT || CHR(10) ||
                                                    'bsa_rec.LOAD_DATE:' || bsa_rec.LOAD_DATE );
    UPDATE WAREHOUSE.BANK_STATEMENT_ACTIVITY
    SET OVERRIDDEN_CHECK_NO       = --(CASE :btn                                          
                                        (CASE WHEN (btn = '1') THEN CASE WHEN bsa_rec.OVERRIDDEN_CHECK_NO = bsa_rec.CHECK_NO THEN NULL
                                                                         WHEN bsa_rec.OVERRIDDEN_CHECK_NO != bsa_rec.CHECK_NO THEN LPAD(TRIM(bsa_rec.OVERRIDDEN_CHECK_NO), 12, '0')
                                                                    END
                                        WHEN (btn = '2') THEN '1740 - Previously Paid Warrant'
                                        ELSE NULL
                                    END),
        OVERRIDDEN_AMOUNT         = --(CASE :btn
                                        (CASE WHEN (btn = '1') THEN CASE WHEN bsa_rec.OVERRIDDEN_AMOUNT = bsa_rec.AMOUNT THEN NULL
                                                                         WHEN bsa_rec.OVERRIDDEN_AMOUNT != bsa_rec.AMOUNT THEN LPAD(TRIM(bsa_rec.OVERRIDDEN_AMOUNT), 12, '0')
                                                                    END
                                        WHEN (btn = '2') THEN NULL
                                        ELSE NULL
                                    END),
        OVERRIDDEN_DATE           = SYSDATE,
        OVERRIDDEN_USER_ID        = bsa_rec.OVERRIDDEN_USER_ID,
        CHECK_NO                  = (CASE btn
                                        WHEN '1' THEN LPAD(TRIM(bsa_rec.CHECK_NO), 12, '0')
                                        WHEN '2' THEN LPAD(TRIM(bsa_rec.CHECK_NO), 12, '0')
                                        ELSE NULL
                                        END),
        AMOUNT                    = (CASE btn
                                        WHEN '1' THEN TRIM(bsa_rec.OVERRIDDEN_AMOUNT)
                                        WHEN '2' THEN TRIM(bsa_rec.AMOUNT)
                                        ELSE NULL
                                        END)
        WHERE TO_NUMBER(CHECK_NO) = (CASE btn
                                        WHEN '1' THEN bsa_rec.OVERRIDDEN_CHECK_NO
                                        WHEN '2' THEN bsa_rec.CHECK_NO
                                        ELSE NULL
                                    END)
        AND AMOUNT                = (CASE btn
                                        WHEN '1' THEN bsa_rec.OVERRIDDEN_AMOUNT
                                        WHEN '2' THEN bsa_rec.AMOUNT
                                        ELSE NULL
                                    END)
        AND TRUNC(LOAD_DATE)      = (CASE btn
                                     WHEN '1' THEN  TRUNC(bsa_rec.LOAD_DATE)
                                     WHEN '2' THEN (SELECT MAX(LOAD_DATE) FROM WAREHOUSE.BANK_STATEMENT_ACTIVITY)
                                     ELSE NULL
                                     END)
        AND BANKACCTNO            = (SELECT LONGDESC 
                                     FROM TCMS.COMPLEMENTARY_VALIDATIONS
                                     WHERE TEXTCODE = 'BANKACCT'
                                     AND CODE = 80);

    COMMIT;
END UpdateBankStatementActivity;
```

The parameter values in the first SQL CODE snippet are consistent with the parameters in the PL/SQL block.

Comment: I believe this should work. Can you please post an example with data before the update, update run ( including variable values) and data after the update. I believe a single not working column would be enough to explain the question.

Comment: mathguy pointed out a falw in the logic which I corrected, and the update works via the editor.  However, when executed via the package, the table is not being updated... I will provide examples as soon as possible.

Comment: @TheSchnitz - make sure you change the code in the procedure in the package, and you recompile everything. Otherwise Oracle will still use the "last known good" version!

Comment: Thanks @mathguy. I have been recompiling and reviewing table data after every attempt when executing via the package.

Comment: I have added the requested information and some additional info. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @TheSchnitz - I "edited" my Answer to address the new code. Please note, I don't think the code, EXACTLY as you have it in the procedure, would produce different results when run directly from your SQL editor (not wrapped within PL/SQL code). Read and you will see why.

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by "not updating"?

There is a clear logical flaw in your nested `case` expressions, when `:btn = '1'`. Namely, the first branch of the "inner" `case` expression always evaluates to TRUE, so the "update value" will be `null` every time you pass in `:btn = '1'`. Is that the problem you are noticing? Then: For `overridden_amount` the result will always be `null` because of this; for `overridden_check_no` it will not be `null` if and only if `:btn = '2'`.

Note that you could write the "outer" `case` expressions with the same syntax you use for the simple expressions: `case :btn when '1' then case .... end else ...   end`.

**EDIT**: Answering your modified question (perhaps). I am not sure I can follow the logic in its entirety; but what is happening in the example (assuming you called the procedure with `btn = '1'` is this:

Both the `overridden_check_no` and the `overridden_amount` are `null` in the original table. In the nested (inner) `case` expression for both columns you check two columns, with either `=` or `!=`. **Neither** of the tests is `true` when one of the terms is `null`! So the `case` evaluations falls through to the `else` clause, or when `else` is not included, to the default, which is `null`. The `update` actually did work, it just updated the values to `null` because none of the "actual branches" in the inner `case` statements evaluated to `true`.

You say, though, that this works OK if you just run it as a stand-alone SQL `update`, directly from your editor. I wonder how that is possible, unless - again - the code in the procedure is different from what you have in your editor.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. Having said that, when I test this alone in the editor it appears to update the table, but when I execute this via my PL/SQL package the table is not updated.

Comment: I feel embarrassed. I just found my error. In my test procedure, I was passing in the incorrect amount that basically made the WHERE clause incorrect for updating the specific test record. Thank you so much for your help! Apologies.